# Count number of cells containing in part a specific string

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if its possible to count cells that has a specific string in it? Like for example I want to use `Mid(C.Value, 6, 2) = "sh"` and count how many data in my spreadsheet has "sh" in it.

What I've got so far is this, I used UsedRange to select all of the data in the spreadsheet, all I need to do if filter and count specific data that has a certain string in it.

```
Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
LastRow = Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim RangeString As String
Worksheets("Campaign").Select
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
RangeString = Selection.Address

Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
RangeString = RangeString & ":" & Selection.Address
```

Comment: is it possible to use a mid function inside the countif statement?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but you can use `"*text*"`, or some limited other wildcards like `?` to match text in particular places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see if *sh* is anywhere in the cells' values then,

```
dim cnt as long
with Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange
    cnt = application.countif(.cells, "*sh*")
    debug.Print cnt
end with
```

If you want to count cells that have *sh* as the sixth and seventh letters in any cell's value then,

```
dim cnt as long
with Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange
    cnt = application.countif(.cells, "?????sh*")
    debug.Print cnt
end with
```

As a wildcard, the asterisk (e.g. `*`) means any number of characters. The question mark (e.g. `?`) means a single character but can be stacked up.
These counts are not case-sensitive.

Comment: A very detailed answer! Thank you, it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do that. First of all why are you using so many selects, I would rather use For loops. Anyways, you can use it like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim count as Integer
count=0

For i = 1 To 6
    if(Instr(Cells(i,1).Text,"sh")) Then
        count=count+1
    End if
Next i
```

I am sorry I couldn't test the code since I am using Ubuntu, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

additional variant from my side to already posted by `@Jeeped`

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, i&: i = 0
    For Each cl In Sheets("Campaign").UsedRange
        If LCase(cl.Value) Like "*sh*" Then i = i + 1
    Next cl
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```